# Load Staging Table SQL Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse, ssis

I am having some serious issue while loading Staging Table from Data Store. My query to load Staging table is taking more then 24 hours to execute.The three main tables are item_ledger_entry = 12 Million,Value_Entry=28 Million and Gl_Entry = 58 Million. The issue is Group By clause with is taking 95% CUP cost for SORT.
Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.
I can email you the query if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting to close- way too little information.

Typical approaches:

- Do not load all data. You really dont need o load unchanged records every day. You have tiny data (we track 40 million rows PER DAY) but the trcick is not to load data that has not changed to start with.
- Better hardware. You dont say anything ywhat you use.
- Avoid group by - what or? Not clear from your question.,

In general: Hire a specialist. Seriously - This sounds like a real high end project and people earn money with their knowledge. If you have a problem at this level, a lot of other things may be wrong, and a thorough answer is way beyond what you can ask here. For example - the query may not be your problem, the hwole approach may suck (as I said: avoid processing data to start with).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to load the data every day as the Stage table gets truncated each day. How Can I extract only the changed data from the Data Store. Data Store contains all historical data which is then passed on to the Staging and then to fact Table.

Comment: iti s called programming. Seriously - one needs to look at the whole system. Hire a specialist. Noone can answer you here without knowing details.